# mocking database connection by using mockito

Tags: junit, mockito, ibatis

```
public List<Prisma> getProductCharacteristics(ResultSetLoadHandler<Prisma> rsLoadHandler, SqlSession sqlSession) throws Exception {
    List<Prisma> ptos = null;
    try {
        sqlSession.select("Product.getProductInformation", params, rsLoadHandler);
        ptos = rsLoadHandler.getResults();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return ptos;
}
```

I am trying to mock the select method

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
    @Override
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return rsLoadHandler;
    }
}).when(sqlSession).select(rsLoadHandler, sqlSession);
```

but not able to mock `sqlSession.select(String statement, Object parameter, ResultHandler handler);` in **mockito** framework.

Getting this issue:

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create
>   PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28000: the account is locked )

I am using **ibatis** database, I need to mock the db calls 
I should not hit the database and return the list size to be greater than zero.